# Does Google Play balance expire?

Tags: google-play-store

I have a credit on Google Play that is from a gift card and not a promotion. Do I have to use it by a certain date?

Answer (score 7):

From the [Google Play Gift Card Terms of Service](https://play.google.com/about/card-terms.html):

> 3. No Fees or Expiration. No fees or expiration dates apply to this Gift Card. Any refunded Google Play amounts, if applicable, will be
>      credited back to your Google Play balance for future use under the
>      same terms, unless otherwise required by law.

This is partially because of [laws around gift cards](http://www.ncsl.org/research/financial-services-and-commerce/gift-cards-and-certificates-statutes-and-legis.aspx):

> In 2009, Congress passed the Credit Card Accountability Responsibility
>   and Disclosure (CARD) Act, which set consumer protections for gift
>   cards based on many state laws. The law provides that gift cards
>   cannot expire within five years from the date they were activated and
>   generally limits inactivity fee on gift cards except in certain
>   circumstances, such as if there has been no transaction for at least
>   12 months. The federal law creates a floor for regulation and leaves
>   room for state regulation on redeeming gift cards for cash and
>   unclaimed property provisions.

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted Ryan Conrad's answer because it is correct, and also provides some interesting additional information. However, it is **correct for the United States**.

Here in Australia, Google Play cards have this clause (unfortunately):

> **3. Expiration Period; No Fees.** Gift Card **value expires 2 years following the date of (1) card issuance, or (2) last activity on Google Play stored value account into which the card is redeemed, whichever is later**. No fees apply to the Gift Card. If required under applicable law, any refunds will be credited back to your Google Play balance for future use under these terms of service, unless otherwise required.

I actually found a card that I had completely forgotten about. Thankfully it still worked!

Answer (score 0):

The answer regarding US cards is false.  Despite the wording on the cards themselves saying there is no expiration date, they still expire after 2 years. If you call and complain, Google will tell you deal with the store that issued them, which is usually impossible.