# How to tell when Google Play Store credit will expire?

Tags: google-play-store

For Google Play Store credit that ***does expire***, how does one see when it expires?

For credits that do ***not*** expire, see [this QA](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/122247/does-google-play-balance-expire).

Answer (score 3):

If you go to [Google Wallet](https://wallet.google.com/manage/#paymentMethods:) payment methods you can see your Google Play credit, how much has an expiry date and when it expires.

[image: screenshot of Google Play balance on Google Wallet]

Comment: Thanks.  When I go to that page, it shows the balance, but does ***not*** indicate the expiration date for the credits that do have expiration dates.  Interesting that it works for you though.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Just a thought but is it possible that it might be of *doesn't expire* kind?

Comment: @SarpSTA I wish that were the case, but Google stated that they do expire.  Unfortunately, I don't see any place within the Google apps / websites that indicate when credits expire.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Weird. Call Google and ask them. They are really helpful.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard (855) 836-3987

Comment: @SarpSTA Unfortunately, after multiple calls to Google, I must say they are incompetent.  All they are able to do is tell me that they don't understand why their billing systems are not working correctly.  They can't fix their billing systems, and despite acknowledging the errors, have not been willing to correct the balance.  It's not the first time their system has stolen money.  I took screenshots, plus they say they can see the errors on their end.  They promised to fix the problem and write back, but they didn't.  It might be time to join the *Goodbye Google* club.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new way to check if have any Google Play credit is about to expire.

Here is how to check:

1. Launch the Google Play store
2. Go to menu options and looking for Payment method option
3. Once you land on payment method option, you should be able to see more detail on your expire credit

I hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

FAQ says it expires 1year after the date of your most recently completed survey

Comment: To what survey are you referring?